# Get size of file while writer is still open on HDFS

Tags: java, hdfs, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to poll the file size of a temp. avro file that's being written to on HDFS from a Kafka Topic, but `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus` keeps returning 0 bytes (`.getLen()`), while the writer is still open and writing.

I could keep a counter of length at the writer end, but deep down the data is converted into a binary format (avro) that differs in length from the original record. It could be approximated, but I'm looking for an more precise solution.

Is there a way to get the size of a still open hdfs file from either the hdfs (`io.confluent.connect.hdfs.storage.HdfsStorage`) perspective or the file writer (`io.confluent.connect.storage.format.RecordWriter`) perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I extended the `RecordWriter` used in the `AvroRecordWriterProvider` and included a wrapper around the `FSDataOutputStream` to poll for current size in the `TopicPartitionWriter`

After legal has cleared it I will push the code to a fork and provide a link to all who are interested.